# Welcher Artikel wird mit "fremden" Zeitformen verwendet?

Tags: article

Zum Beispiel:

> (a) … kann durch **Present Continuous** ersetzt werden.
>
> (b) **Trapassato prossimo** ist eine Verbform, die …

Ich bin schon mal über „der“ und „das“ gestolpert. Welcher Artikel soll vor den fett markierten Zeitformen gebraucht werden?

Comment: Wahrscheinlich denselben wie z.B. für "**das** Futur", "**das** Perfekt" und "**das** Plusquamperfekt".

Comment: Das Problem ist nicht auch grammatische Begriffe beschränkt, sondern tritt immer auf, wenn Wörter aus einer fremden Sprache in einem deutschsprachigen Kontext verwendet werden. Dazu wurden hier schon unzählige Fragen gestellt und beantwortet.

Answer (score -1):

Wie immer: Es gibt keine klare Festlegung.

Mögliche Kriterien für die Wahl des Genus und damit des zuverwendenden Artikels könnten sein:

1. Übernahme des Genus der deutschen Übersetzung:

> Present Continuous → das kontinuierliche Präsens → *das* Present Continuous

2. Übernahme des Genus der Muttersprache:

> trapassato → (m) → *der* Trapassato Prossimo

(Achtung: Das geht natürlich nur in Sprachen, die über Genera ähnlich dem Deutschen verfügen.)

3. Generisches Neutrum:

> *Das* Present Continuous
>   *Das* Trapassato Prossimo

4. Lautmalung (sehr subjektiv)

Bei diesen beiden Wörtern lassen sich also sowohl `das` als auch `der` gut erklären. Für `die` bräuchte man eine starke, lautmalerische Tendenz zum Feminimum.

Comment: Warum schreibst du in (1) »***der*** kontinuierliche Präsens«? Das Substantiv *Präsens* ist doch sächlich, zumindest behaupten das [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Präsens), [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Praesens) und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Präsens). Sollte es daher nicht »***das*** kontinuierliche Präsens« heißen?

Comment: Die Strategie 2 (Übernahme aus der Ursprungssprache) (Muttersprache ist der falsche Begriff) ist äußerst problematisch, vor allem wenn das Genussystem der Ursprungssprache sich vom deutschen System unterscheidet. Italienisch hat nur zwei Geschlechter (männlich und weiblich). Daher kann nach dieser Logik kein italienisches Fremdwort sächlich sein. Welches Geschlecht soll man nach dieser Logik schwedischen Fremdwörtern geben, deren Geschlecht *utrum* ist? Das ist nämlich ein Geschlecht, das es im Deutschen nicht gibt.

Comment: Die Übernahme des Genus aus der ursprünglichen Sprache funktioniert natürlich nur bei Sprachen wie Italienisch oder Spanisch, wo das Genus (normalerweise) leicht an der Endung der Wörter zu erkennen ist.

Comment: @mach Und weil man das Genus italienischer Worte so gut an der Endung erkennen kann,
heißt es auch "das Violoncello", "das Adagio", "das Crescendo", 
"das Konto", "das Disagio", "das Pesto", "das Risotto", "das Carpaccio" und "das Tiramisu".

Comment: Die Übernahme des Genus funktioniert noch am ehesten bei einer Sprache wie Latein, die wie das Deutsche Maskulinum, Femininum und Neutrum hat. Bei Sprachen mit einem anderen Genussystem ist sie in der Tat fragwürdig.

Comment: @RHa Genauer gesagt:
Sie funktioniert bei Latein und Altgriechisch. Und nur da.
Das liegt nicht daran, daß diese beiden Sprachen wie das Deutsche
ein Drei-Genus-System haben, sondern daran, daß es sich hier
typischerweise um *gelehrte* Entlehnungen handelt, um Entlehnungen
durch Wissenschaftler des 17. bis frühen 20. Jahrhunderts.
Diese waren (a) des Lateinischen und Griechischen
mächtig, und sie haben (b) das Genus dieser Sprachen *durchgängig*
übernommen.
Für Entlehnungen aus anderen Sprachen hat das Genus in der
Ausgangssprache etwa die gleiche Bedeutung wie ein Würfelwurf.

Comment: Wie soll man denn deinen letzten Satz verstehen? Eine "starke lautmalerische Tendenz" (was könnte das denn sein?) führt zu einem Femininum?

Comment: Ah hups, das hab ich doch seit Jahren gedacht, 'Präsens' wäre maskulin. Da muss ich die Antwort wohl umschreiben.